# Where is the mistake here (proof of the dot product)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Consider two vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb R^n$, if we sum up those two vectors we will get a parallelogram with sides length $\vec{u},\vec{v}$.
And in this parallelogram we have two triangles With sides length $\vec{u},\vec{v}, \vec{u}+\vec{v}$.

By the law of cosine :
$$\| \vec{u}+\vec{v} \|^2= \|\vec{u}\|^2+\|\vec{v}\|^2-2 \|\vec{u}\|\|\vec{v}\|\cos(\theta) $$

Where $\theta$ Is the angle between $\vec{u}+\vec{v}$
$$(\vec{u}+\vec{v})(\vec{u}+\vec{v})= \vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}+ \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} -2 \|\vec{u}\|\|\vec{v}\|\cos(\theta)  $$
$$2 \vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=-2 \|\vec{u}\|\|\vec{v}\|\cos(\theta)  $$
And then $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=-\|\vec{u}\|\|\vec{v}\|\cos(\theta)  $$
What is that? I’m sure that the formula of dot product with no minus sign, i’ve checked the proof a lot of times but i didn’t found any mistake, can you tell me  where is it?

Here’s a quick picture :
[image]

Comment: Why is there a minus sign in the first part?

Comment: It is from the law of cosine @Gregory

Comment: Your $\theta$ would be the angle between $u$ and $u+v$, not the angle between $u$ and $v$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw the picture in the plane. You want the angle between $u$ and $v$ in the triangle with third side $u-v$, not $u+v$. That's the other diagonal of the parallelogram.

Comment: See the picture @Ethan Bolker

Comment: In your picture the angle "between $u$ and $v$" is at $A$, not $B$. The angle at $B$ is the angle between $u$ and $-v$, so the supplement of the one you want. Hence the negative.

Answer (score 1):

The $\theta$ in your equation is the angle opposite $\vec{u} + \vec{v}$ in your triangle.  This is not the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

If you continue the line along $\vec{u}$, you will see that your $\theta$ is the supplementary angle to the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.  So the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $\pi - \theta$.  Of course $\cos \theta = - \cos(\pi - \theta)$.